# i want to send the data taken from the database into mailcomposer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am sending the data taken from the database into the mail composer.

i have taken the data into a array from database  and i have converted it into string but when i am adding the data in to mail composer it is coming in random number .

here is the code that am using to add the array taken from data base into string and then adding to mail body.

```
NSString *arr1 =[[appDelegate.list1 UTF8String] componentsJoinedByString:@","];


[picker setMessageBody:arr1  isHTML:NO];
```

if any one have the answer pls give me.

Comment: First verify that your string contains what you think it should (set a breakpoint in the debugger or use NSLog to print out the string).

Answer (score 0):

```
[[appDelegate.list1 UTF8String] componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

What do you want here? If `list1` is an array it won't response to `-UTF8String`, and if it is a string, the method will return a `const char*` which is not an Objective-C object and thus will crash on `-componentsJoinedByString:`.

Either use

```
NSString *arr1 = appDelegate.list1; // if it is a string
```

or

```
// if it is an array.
NSString *arr1 = [appDelegate.list1 componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

Comment: list1 is array , i am using the your second option but i am getting the random number in mail composer.
how can i use UTF8String for array.

Comment: @uttam: NSString is encoding agnostic, the encoding won't affect how the composer show stuff. If you see random number the other parts of the code are wrong.